# How to know which name will have my view tpl file?

Tags: views, entities, theming

Currently i have a view with the name:

name (String, 21 characters ) home_slideshow_mobile

At the same time this view content is displayed inside a block, which filename (tpl.php) should it have my template file to rewrite the content of this view?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple templates for views like :

```
views-view--home-slideshow-mobile.tpl.php
```

if your display is a block, you can write it like this :

```
views-view--home-slideshow-mobile--block.tpl.php
```

then you have templates for views fields :

```
views-view-fields--home-slideshow-mobile.tpl.php
```

Templates for views format (like unformatted for example) :

```
views-view-unformatted--home-slideshow-mobile.tpl.php
```

If you want to alter the template of your block, you can declare a `block.tpl.php` like :

```
block--my-block-module--my-block-machinename.tpl.php
```

You can check all views template in the module views (in like `sites/all/contrib/views/theme/...`). You can copy the template and paste them in your theme and rename it to target your specific view.

Comment: What if instead of unformatted be an html list? which would be the name?

Comment: It would be html-list instead of unformatted I guess. I'm glad that worked for you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7

See the suggestion for views templates.

If You calling a view block in your custom tpl.php use
echo views_embed_view('view_machine_name', 'block_1');
You can find out the display name by clicking the tab and check its name in the address bar of your browser: "#views-tab-block_1" gives you "block_1'.

Answer (score 1):

In your views, you can get a theme suggestions by clicking **Theme:  information** under **Advanced** settings of your view. It gives you suggestion for every field, view style etc.